# superset docker compose not able to have data persistence

Tags: apache-superset

we are using superset docker compose as per the installation guide, However, once the docker is crashed or machine is restarted, we need to re-configure dashboard.. not sure how to configure with persistence volume that it can continue work after restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default superset docker-compose has PostgreSQL db service and data's are mounted as volume, which is holding all of data related to superset. So instead of using default db service use extranal database instance in that case even docker-compose restart you'll not loose your data.

Comment: how do you save all the chart settings?